# C# WebClient Download file from FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I am using the following code to download file from FTP.

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.FTPUserName, Properties.Settings.Default.FTPPassword);
string inputfilepath = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.LocalDownloadFolder, file);
string ftpfullpath = Properties.Settings.Default.FTPSite + Properties.Settings.Default.FTPFolder + file;

WebClient request1 = new WebClient();
request1.Credentials = credential;
request1.DownloadFile(ftpfullpath, inputfilepath);
```

Values of the first two vaiables is:

```
E:\FTPDownloads\CardholderManagementReport_1030_2012-12-11.xls
ftp://abc.com/AKSHAY/CardholderManagementReport_1030_2012-12-11.xls
```

It shows error as :

```
The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
```

**EDIT:
I can see that the file is indeed present there, credentials are ok and I can download it using FileZilla**

Comment: And what is the question? Do you not understand error message?

Comment: Does this answer helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6098905/435693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.colourcoding.net/blog/archive/2010/01/25/ftpwebrequest-and-550-file-unavailable-e.g.-file-not-found-no.aspx) makes it work.
ftp://abc.com/%2f/AKSHAY/CardholderManagementReport_1030_2012-12-11.xls
Explaination is also there.

Answer (score 0):

The error 550 returned by the FTP server indicates that the user you are using to try and access the file with does not have permission to access the file.

Either use some other set of credentials that has access to the file or change the permissions on the file to allow access.

Comment: request1.Credentials = credential; This lne sets the credentials and it is created in a line that I have not mentioned in the code.