# Upload file to FTP site using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have this working code from this [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=468649), to upload a file to an ftp site:

```
' set up request...
Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = _
    DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.myserver.com/test.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword")
clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

' read in file...
Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Temp\test.txt")

' upload file...
Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
    clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
clsStream.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length)
clsStream.Close()
clsStream.Dispose()
```

I wonder, if the file already exists in the ftp directory, the file will be overwritten?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.uploadfile.aspx) documentation this maps to the FTP STOR command.  Looking at the definition for the FTP STOR command it will overwrite existing files, if the user has permissions.

So in this case, yes the file would be overwritten.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, FTP protocol overwrites existing files on upload.

---

Note that there are better ways to implement the upload.

The most trivial way to upload a binary file to an FTP server using .NET framework is using [`WebClient.UploadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile):

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
client.UploadFile("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip", "C:\local\path\file.zip")
```

If you need a greater control, that `WebClient` does not offer (like [TLS/SSL encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848#56888555), ascii/text transfer mode, active mode, transfer resuming, etc), use [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest). Easy way is to just copy a `FileStream` to FTP stream using [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto):

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Using fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip"),
      ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream)
End Using
```

If you need to monitor an upload progress, you have to copy the contents by chunks yourself:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest =
    WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Using fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip"),
      ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim read As Integer
    Do
        Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(10240) {}
        read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        If read > 0 Then
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
            Console.WriteLine("Uploaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position)
        End If
    Loop While read > 0
End Using
```

For GUI progress (WinForms `ProgressBar`), see C# example at:
[How can we show progress bar for upload with FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6341024/850848#45931971)

If you want to upload all files from a folder, see C# example at
[Upload directory of files to FTP server using WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44012637/850848).

Comment: This answer is pefect, a good addition to it is how to create directories on your ftp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031336/how-to-create-directory-on-ftp-server

Comment: Used WebClient.DownloadFile, which is similar, to download a file from an FTP site, and works well as well. Upvoted, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From: [Link](http://www.ipswitch.com/support/ws_ftp-server/guide/v5/a_ftpref3.html)

STOR (STORE)

STOR

This command causes the FTP server to accept the data transferred via the data connection and to store the data as a file at the FTP server. If the file specified in pathname exists at the server site, then its contents shall be replaced by the data being transferred. A new file is created at the FTP server if the file specified in pathname does not already exist.

Answer (score -1):

Use This Function to Upload file

Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String, ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)

Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)

```
' Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

' Provide the WebPermission Credintials
_FtpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)

' By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
' after a command is executed.
_FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False

' set timeout for 20 seconds
_FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000

' Specify the command to be executed.
_FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

' Specify the data transfer type.
_FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True

' Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
_FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length

' The buffer size is set to 2kb
Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte

' Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()

Try
    ' Stream to which the file to be upload is written
    Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

    ' Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
    Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)

    ' Till Stream content ends
    Do While contentLen <> 0
        ' Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
        _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
        contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
    Loop

    ' Close the file stream and the Request Stream
    _Stream.Close()
    _Stream.Dispose()
    _FileStream.Close()
    _FileStream.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

End Sub

HOW TO USE:

' Upload file using FTP
UploadFile("c:\UploadFile.doc", "ftp://FTPHostName/UploadPath/UploadFile.doc", "UserName", "Password")

Answer (score -1):

this is working code to upload files to a FTP server

```
               Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(New Uri("ftp://" & server & "/" & folderName & "/" & filename)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
                        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
                        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)
                        request.UseBinary = True
                        request.UsePassive = True

                        Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
                        Dim bytesIn As Long = 1
                        Dim totalBytesIn As Long = 0

                        Dim filepath As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(file)
                        Dim ftpstream As System.IO.FileStream = filepath.OpenRead()
                        Dim flLength As Long = ftpstream.Length
                        Dim reqfile As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

                        Do Until bytesIn < 1
                            bytesIn = ftpstream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
                            If bytesIn > 0 Then
                                reqfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesIn)
                                totalBytesIn += bytesIn
                            End If
                        Loop

                        reqfile.Close()
                        ftpstream.Close()
```