# Upload directory of files to FTP server using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, webclient

I have searched and searched and cannot find a way to do this.  I have files in a directory I want to upload.  The file names change constantly so I cannot upload by file name. Here is what I have tried.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Password");
    foreach (var filePath in files)
        client.UploadFile("ftp://site.net//PICS_CAM1//", "STOR", @"PICS_CAM1\");
}
```

But I am getting a compiler error:

> The name 'files' does not exist in the current context

Everything I have researched says this should work.

Does anyone have a good way to upload a directory of files via `WebClient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define and set the `files`. If you wanted to upload all files in a certain local directory, use for example [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles).

Also the `address` argument of [`WebClient.UploadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile) has to be a full URL to a target file, not just a URL to a target directory.

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\local\folder");

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        client.UploadFile(
            "ftp://example.com/remote/folder/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
    }
}
```

For a recursive upload, see:
[Recursive upload to FTP server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925131/850848)

Answer (score 0):

I think your web client upload will work fine. Your issue is that your variable `files` is not in scope.

You need to post more of your code so we can see better