# Tried example of FTP Upload from VB code

Tags: vb.net, ftp

Thanks to Martin Prikryl for three examples on page [Upload file to FTP site using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809279/upload-file-to-ftp-site-using-vb-net)
But I keep getting "Catch e" errors about not logged on or can't connect to server on two different servers.  I can FTP to these servers using PuttyFTP or FileZilla.  In each case, the statement that passes the Server IP address and destination path/file shows an exception when the object is right-clicked.[Notated screen cap while stepping thru Upload routine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xvTm.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated, please.

Answer (score 0):

If by "PuttyFTP" (which does not seem to exist) you mean [`psftp`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html), then you are using SFTP protocol, not FTP protocol.

These two are completely different and incompatible protocols.

There's no native support for SFTP in .NET. You have to use a 3rd party library.

- [How do I upload a file to an SFTP server in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86458/850848)
- [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848)

Comment: Yes, PuttyFTP is psftp "under the hood".  Thank you.  I was only using it as a cross-check, but what you wrote lets me know it was a bogus check.  My exception issues when using your suggested VB code remain, however.   Please click the "Notated screen cap..." in the original post to see the exception messages.  Is there some sort of permissions that must be set in the server to allow this upload?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. So are you sure you are connecting to FTP server? Can you successfully connect using any (standalone) FTP client? Show us its log file.

Comment: I am able to access our private AWS server, which is an instance of Debian, using FileZilla.  But now I see FileZilla is using SFTP.  I just looked for VB SFTP examples and will try them.  Thanks.  

PS:  This is the (redacted) FileZilla log of a connect and transfer:
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to ##.59.88.###...
Status: Connected to ##.59.88.###
Status: Starting upload of S:\OrangePi\Scripts_Cloud_1123\index.html
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 2,140 bytes in 1 second
Status: Disconnected from server

Comment: OK, so I've answered your question in the end, right? Please, consider accepting my answer.