# SSIS Task - FTP Conecction

Tags: ssis, ftp, ftps, script-task

All,

SSIS - trying to make an ftp connection to upload files to an ftp server using a script task in visual basic programming language, I have run into a problem. I have not found something similar in my searches so I would appreciate your help.

[Connection manager "FTP"] Error: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: 220
550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel

CODE:

Public Sub Main()

```
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '

    Try

        Dim cm As ConnectionManager

        cm = Dts.Connections("FTP")

        'Set the properties like username & password
        cm.Properties("ServerName").SetValue(cm, "ftps.example.com")
        cm.Properties("ServerUserName").SetValue(cm, "username")
        cm.Properties("ServerPassword").SetValue(cm, "password")
        cm.Properties("ServerPort").SetValue(cm, "port")
        cm.Properties("Timeout").SetValue(cm, "0") 'The 0 setting will make it not timeout
        cm.Properties("ChunkSize").SetValue(cm, "1000") '1000 kb
        cm.Properties("Retries").SetValue(cm, "1")

        'create the FTP object that sends the files and pass it the connection created above.

        Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = New FtpClientConnection(cm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))

        'Connects to the ftp server

        ftp.Connect()


        'Build a array of all the file names that is going to be FTP'ed (in this case only one file)

        Dim files(0) As String

        files(0) = "C:\ local path file"

        'ftp the file 

        ftp.SendFiles(files, "/remote path", True, False) ' the True makes it overwrite existing file and False is saying that it is not transferring ASCII

        ftp.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dts.TaskResult = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure


    End Try
```

Comment: I didn't find any documentation for those FTP connection properties. And once you code everything anyway, why don't you use the standard .NET `FtpWebRequest` and its `EnableSsl = True`?  See [Upload file to FTP site using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809279/850848#46089558).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...... I finally solved it. I changed the language script task to C# (it works in VB you just have to adapt the code) and used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331665/ftps-ftp-over-ssl-in-c-sharp#56888555) comment.

note: if the server is on a port other than 21 you have to specify it in the remote path. thanks.

```
   public void Main()
   {
    // TODO: Add your code here
     FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftps.example.com:port/remote/path/file.zip");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        request.EnableSsl = true;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\local\path\file.zip"))
        using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
          {
        fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
          }
    }
```